# Mongodb find query for array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm trying - find query for array in mongodb,

- db.users.find({posts:{$all:[_id : ObjectId("5cc83a158ceb346aa58b1161")]}})
- db.users.find( { "posts.post" : {$all : []}})

//My MongoDB collections

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
```

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5cc83a158ceb346aa58b1161"),
"friends" : [ ],
"name" : "krishna soni",
"email" : "krishnasoni@gmail.com",
"password" : "krishna",
"posts" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cc8478118195b71e2ccd517"),
        "post" : "hey users",
        "createdTime" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:02:57.621Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cc853ec0a5fde0e431898f3"),
        "post" : "hey friends it's my final post",
        "createdTime" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:55:56.119Z")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

//expected results is following 
//display given objectId's posts array

```
"posts" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cc8478118195b71e2ccd517"),
        "post" : "hey users",
        "createdTime" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:02:57.621Z")
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cc853ec0a5fde0e431898f3"),
        "post" : "hey friends it's my final post",
        "createdTime" : ISODate("2019-04-30T13:55:56.119Z")
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass `{posts:1}`

Try this:

```
db.users.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5cc83a158ceb346aa58b1161")},{posts:1});
```